# How to run a background service in cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, background-service

I need to know about how to run a background service to give notifications in `cordova` mobile application. I went through a plugin [this](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/tree/example-x) but in that example when i clicked the 'Interval' option which is triggering notification for every minute when only app was opened or paused. It wasn't triggering any notification when app was killed(Swipe out from recent tasks) on background. So is there any alternative option to run the process in background in `cordova`applications

Answer (score 0):

> According to phonegap/Cordova documentation their is no way to run
>   background service because phone can not execute javascript when your
>   app is not running.Yet no plugin was available to perform this task

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply @waqar abbas. Is there any other technology like cordova which will perform background tasks

Comment: The text is marked as a quote, but I can not find it on the Internet